# Adding custom variable to Omnipay Paypal Express

Tags: laravel, paypal, laravel-5, omnipay

I have tried searching everywhere on the internet and cannot get anything out there to work.

I am trying to add the user id to my 'Paypal_Express' Omnipay purchase.

However the solution outlined in https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal/issues/10 does not work for me. It says function sendData does not exist. $request->setTransactionId(); and $request->setDescription(); also throws an error.. Has anyone else been able to do this?

```
$order_paramaters = array(
'amount'       => $grand_total,
);

Omnipay::setParameter('custom', $cart->user_id);
$response = Omnipay::purchase($order_paramaters)->send();
```

I get:

```
call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, cannot access protected method Omnipay\PayPal\ExpressGateway::setParameter()
```

Also tried:

```
$gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
$gateway->setParameter('custom', $cart->user_id);
$response = $gateway->purchase($order_paramaters)->send();
```

I get:

```
Call to protected method Omnipay\Common\AbstractGateway::setParameter() from context 'App\Http\Controllers\CartController'
```

Any help GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of this:

```
$gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
$gateway->setParameter('custom', $cart->user_id);
$response = $gateway->purchase($order_paramaters)->send();
```

You need to try this:

```
$gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Express');
$purchase = $gateway->purchase($order_paramaters);
$purchase->setParameter('custom', $cart->user_id);
$response = $purchase->send();
```

i.e. the `custom` parameter is a parameter of the purchase object, not of the gateway object.